# capture incoming telnet requests all the time using tcpdump

Tags: monitoring, bash, telnet

I want to check if I get any incoming telnet request. After doing google, I found out that `tcpdump` can be used for this purpose. This is the `tcpdump` command I would use.

```
$ tcpdump -i wlan0 -w telReqCapt.pcap 'dest host <myIpAddress> and port 23'
```

However I am not able to think of a way so that this monitoring is ALWAYS done. How do I do this ?

I have thought of few approach.

1. After everytime I log-in, I will run the `tcpdump` command. However this has to be done manually everytime.
2. I will add the `tcpdump` command in me `~/.bashrc` so that everytime I open the terminal, the `tcpdump` command will run. But I dont know what will happen if I open two terminals (or two bash session) at same time. I feel there will be an issue because both the `tcpdump` will try to write to same file.
3. Write a bash script containing the `tcpdump` command and make it run everytime system boots using `upstart` (`/etc/init/`)(I use ubuntu) or by putting the script in `/etc/init.d`.

I think approach 3 is best suited for my needs, because I want to monitor if I get incoming telnet requests for the entire time (since my machine boots, untill it is powered off).

However please let me know if this approach has any problem with it ? Can I start `tcpdump` everytime my system boots ? Is there anyuthing I need to take care of while following this approach. Any performance issues ?

Finally, is there ANY OTHER way I can use `tcpdump` to capture incoming `telnet` requests all the time (since the time the machine boots up untill it is powered off).

Comment: Just thinking out loud, why not let Netcat listen on TCP/23, forward the traffic to an alternative TCP port where the telnet daemon is listening on and let Netcat log everything to a file? TCP Dump seems to be quite "heavy" for just this job.

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox thank you for the suggestion. I will try to learn `netcat`. I recently learned `tcpdump` so I was thinking I will use it to see if i get any telnet requests ..

Comment: Don't use tpcdump. Use iptables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to start automatically when you turn the computer on, writing a startup script like you describe in option 3 is the best.  The important thing to remember is that the environment, particularly the search path and current working directory, may not be what you expect.  Use full paths (not relative paths) everywhere.

If you want to start manually but have it keep running until shutdown, there are programs such as `nohup` or `screen` that let you do this.